# How to compare a value of a single column over multiple columns in the same row using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
np.random.seed(21) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'])
df['current_State'] = [df['B1'][0], df['B1'][1], df['B2'][2], df['B2'][3], df['B3'][4], df['B3'][5], df['B1'][6], df['B2'][7]]
df
```

[image: Click here to see the df]

I need to create a new column that contains the name of the column where the value of 'current_State' is the same, this is the desired output:

[image: desired output]

I tried many combinations of apply and lambda functions but without success. Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the `current_State` column with all the remaining columns to create a boolean mask, then use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) along `axis=1` on this `mask` to get the name of the column where the value in the given row equal to corresponding value in `current_State`:

```
c = 'current_State'
df['new_column'] = df.drop(c, 1).eq(df[c], axis=0).idxmax(1)
```

In case if there is a possibility that there are no matching values we can instead use:

```
c = 'current_State'
m = df.drop(c, 1).eq(df[c], axis=0)
df['new_column'] = m.idxmax(1).mask(~m.any(1))
```

---

```
>>> df

          A        B1        B2        B3  current_State new_column
0 -0.051964 -0.111196  1.041797 -1.256739      -0.111196         B1
1  0.745388 -1.711054 -0.205864 -0.234571      -1.711054         B1
2  1.128144 -0.012626 -0.613200  1.373688      -0.613200         B2
3  1.610992 -0.689228  0.691924 -0.448116       0.691924         B2
4  0.162342  0.257229 -1.275456  0.064004       0.064004         B3
5 -1.061857 -0.989368 -0.457723 -1.984182      -1.984182         B3
6 -1.476442  0.231803  0.644159  0.852123       0.231803         B1
7 -0.464019  0.697177  1.567882  1.178556       1.567882         B2
```

Comment: Great answer considering OP only posted an image (frowned upon).  So curiouis how you obtained the values for the DataFrame (hopefully did have to enter by hand)?

Comment: Thank you very much, @Shubham, for your answer, that was a quite elegant solution and works perfectly in my case

Comment: Thanks @DarrylG i didn't entered the values by hand :) I guess you missed the part in the question where the code to generate the sample dataframe is given.

Comment: @DianaMenesesGustin Glad i could help!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma--yes, I missed that line.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Upvoted OP question (in addtion to your answer) for the thorough posts.